# Why subclipse doesn't work in myeclipse?

Tags: svn, subclipse, myeclipse

I have installed subclipse in Myeclipse,however it doesn't work,when i tried to import project from svn,(ex.type url http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant),the IDE warned that "**Unable to load a svn client**",but i have subclipse already!Why?How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the JavaHL plugin installed.  If you are not on Windows, you need to provide the native library for JavaHL as well.  See:

[subclipse
Wiki: JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL)

Answer (score 0):

You should also install the JavaHL client and the SVNKit (Pure Java) client. The latter is an optional related software but necessary if the JavaHL client cannot be loaded for some reason. To load the related software, go to the Configuration Center (Help->MyEclipse Configuration Center) and click on the Software tab. In the My Software panel, locate Subclipse, right click on it and select View Details. Now select the related software pieces that you want and then click on "finished viewing details" (GUI reponse may be slow, so wait, if you don't get immediate feedback). Eventually, you should see Pending Changes and an Apply button. Click the apply button and follow the wizard.

You can set the client to be used in the SVN preferences (Window->Preferences->Team->SVN).

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Before install this plugin update MyEclipse IDE.

I. Goto `Help` -> `MyEclipse Configuration Center` -> click on `Software` tab then 
click on **add site** link button at **Browser Software** textbox, a pop will be opens.

II. In `Name` textbox field enter **Subclipse 1.8.x Update site**,

in `URL` textbox filed enter `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x`

then click on `OK` button.
**This link is for downloading subclipse into MyEclipse.**
Displays like below

[image: Subclipse before installation]

III. At **Software Updates Available** field click on `Apply 6 Changes` button, it downloads the svn related files into your system.

IV. A `Pulse Explorer` window is appeared click on checkbox and click `Next` button.

Shows as below.

[image: Pulse Explorer]

After completion it asks `restart` MyEclipse button then click on `OK` button.